JWT Token Not Being Set in Cookie (Turns Red in Console), but Test Value Works
I am developing a web application and trying to set a JWT token manually via the browser's console. However, when I try to set the token, it doesn't get stored in the cookies and is highlighted in red in the console.
there is an example cookie
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTI0OCwiYWdlbnQiOnsiaWQiOjEyNDgsInBpY3R1cmUiOiIvQWdlbnQvMTI0OC9waWN0dXJlLzE3Mjg0NzYwMzUzODUtQ2FwdHVyZSBkJ8ODwqljcmFuIDIwMjQtMDctMTUgMTEyNjE3LnBuZyIsImZpcnN0X25hbWUiOiJ5b2FuIGFkcmllbnNxc3MiLCJsYXN0X25hbWUiOiJrcGF0Y2hhdmkiLCJkYXRlX29mX2JpcnRoIjoiMjAyNC0wMy0xMFQxNjoyMjowMi4xOTNaIiwicm9sZSI6MSwibWFuYWdlcl9pZCI6bnVsbCwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0IiwicGhvbmUiOiJOVUxMIiwibW9tbyI6IjA3NTgwMzg3NDQiLCJhZGRyZXNzIjoiMTQgcnVlIGNvcm5laWxsZSIsImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDIzLTEyLTA2VDAwOjA2OjQ5LjQwMFoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyMy0xMi0wNlQwMDowNjo0OS40MDBaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9ieSI6bnVsbCwiY2FyZF9pZCI6IjE5NS04My0xOTYtMjciLCJBcmVhcyI6W3siaWQiOjEyLCJuYW1lIjoiQ2FsYXZpIDMiLCJub3RlcyI6bnVsbCwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjMtMTItMzBUMjM6MTg6NTMuOTIzWiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDIzLTEyLTMwVDIzOjE4OjUzLjkyM1oiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2J5IjpudWxsLCJnZW9tIjpudWxsLCJBZ2VudEFyZWEiOnsiaWQiOjksImFnZW50X2lkIjoxMjQ4LCJhcmVhX2lkIjoxMiwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMDEtMTRUMTE6MjQ6MjMuMDE4WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDI0LTAxLTE0VDExOjI0OjIzLjAxOFoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2J5IjpudWxsfSwiU2l0ZXMiOlt7ImlkIjo4MywibmFtZSI6InNpdGUiLCJjdXN0b21lcl9pZCI6NDQ5LCJhcmVhIjoxMiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6ImRxZHFkcSIsInBob25lIjpudWxsLCJlbWFpbCI6bnVsbCwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMDktMThUMTk6MjU6MjQuNzg2WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDI0LTA5LTE4VDE5OjI1OjI0Ljc4NloiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2J5IjpudWxsfSx7ImlkIjo1OSwibmFtZSI6Ind3d2ogOzs7IiwiY3VzdG9tZXJfaWQiOjExLCJhcmVhIjoxMiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6ImxuLG4iLCJwaG9uZSI6bnVsbCwiZW1haWwiOm51bGwsImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDI0LTA0LTExVDE1OjAwOjM1LjM0NVoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyNC0wNC0xMVQxNTowMDozNS4zNDVaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9ieSI6bnVsbH0seyJpZCI6NjksIm5hbWUiOiJ3d3dqIDs7OyIsImN1c3RvbWVyX2lkIjoxMSwiYXJlYSI6MTIsImFkZHJlc3MiOiJsbixuIiwicGhvbmUiOm51bGwsImVtYWlsIjpudWxsLCJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyNC0wNC0xMVQxNTowMDozNy42MDhaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMDQtMTFUMTU6MDA6MzcuNjA4WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYnkiOm51bGx9LHsiaWQiOjYsIm5hbWUiOiJTacOoZ2UgT2xhdGVjaCBCw6luaW4iLCJjdXN0b21lcl9pZCI6NSwiYXJlYSI6MTIsImFkZHJlc3MiOiIxNCBSdWUgQ29ybmVpbGxlIiwicGhvbmUiOiIwNzU4MDM4NzQ0IiwiZW1haWwiOiJ5a3BhdGNoYXZpQG9sYXRlY2hzbi5jb20iLCJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyMy0xMC0zMFQxOTo1NDoyMC4zNDRaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjMtMTAtMzBUMTk6NTQ6MjAuMzQ0WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYnkiOjEyfSx7ImlkIjo3MywibmFtZSI6IkFNQkFTU0FERSA1IiwiY3VzdG9tZXJfaWQiOjExLCJhcmVhIjoxMiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6IjE0IHJ1ZSBjb3JuZWlsbGUiLCJwaG9uZSI6bnVsbCwiZW1haWwiOm51bGwsImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDI0LTA5LTA0VDE4OjAxOjIxLjI0M1oiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyNC0wOS0wNFQxODowMToyMS4yNDNaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9ieSI6bnVsbH0seyJpZCI6OTAsIm5hbWUiOiJNQUlTT04gRElDS09ERVQiLCJjdXN0b21lcl9pZCI6NDYzLCJhcmVhIjoxMiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6Ik7CsCBERSBQQVJDRUxMRSBLIiwicGhvbmUiOiI5NDAxMTU4NCIsImVtYWlsIjoidmFsZW50aW4uZGlja29kZXRAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMTAtMTFUMjE6MzY6MDkuNDA3WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDI0LTEwLTExVDIxOjM2OjA5LjQwN1oiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2J5IjpudWxsfSx7ImlkIjo5MSwibmFtZSI6IkVOVFJFUE9UIiwiY3VzdG9tZXJfaWQiOjk3LCJhcmVhIjoxMiwiYWRkcmVzcyI6IjYyIHJ1ZSBkdSBzb2xheWVyIiwicGhvbmUiOiIwNjE3NzA1ODg1IiwiZW1haWwiOiJ2YWxlbnRpbi5kaWNrb2RldEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyNC0xMC0xM1QxNjo0ODozNC4zNzlaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMTAtMTNUMTY6NDg6MzQuMzc5WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYnkiOm51bGx9XX0seyJpZCI6MTMsIm5hbWUiOiJOb3JkIiwibm90ZXMiOm51bGwsImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDI0LTAxLTEzVDEzOjAyOjExLjc0NVoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyNC0wMS0xM1QxMzowMjoxMS43NDVaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9ieSI6bnVsbCwiZ2VvbSI6bnVsbCwiQWdlbnRBcmVhIjp7ImlkIjoxNSwiYWdlbnRfaWQiOjEyNDgsImFyZWFfaWQiOjEzLCJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyNC0wMS0xNFQxODoxNjozMC40NjJaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMDEtMTRUMTg6MTY6MzAuNDYyWiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYnkiOm51bGx9LCJTaXRlcyI6W3siaWQiOjU4LCJuYW1lIjoid3d3aiA7OzsiLCJjdXN0b21lcl9pZCI6MTEsImFyZWEiOjEzLCJhZGRyZXNzIjoibG4sbiIsInBob25lIjpudWxsLCJlbWFpbCI6bnVsbCwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMDQtMTFUMTU6MDA6MzQuMjk1WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDI0LTA0LTExVDE1OjAwOjM0LjI5NVoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2J5IjpudWxsfSx7ImlkIjoyOCwibmFtZSI6IlNpdGUgcHJpbmNpcGFsIiwiY3VzdG9tZXJfaWQiOjI5NCwiYXJlYSI6MTMsImFkZHJlc3MiOm51bGwsInBob25lIjpudWxsLCJlbWFpbCI6bnVsbCwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMDEtMDhUMTQ6NDI6MzEuODY0WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDI0LTAxLTA4VDE0OjQyOjMxLjg2NFoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2J5IjpudWxsfSx7ImlkIjo1NCwibmFtZSI6Ind3dyIsImN1c3RvbWVyX2lkIjoxMSwiYXJlYSI6MTMsImFkZHJlc3MiOiJsbixuIiwicGhvbmUiOm51bGwsImVtYWlsIjpudWxsLCJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyNC0wNC0xMVQxNDo1OTozNy4xNzZaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMDQtMTFUMTQ6NTk6MzcuMTc2WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYnkiOm51bGx9LHsiaWQiOjcxLCJuYW1lIjoiTWFpc29uIHByaW5jaXBhbGUiLCJjdXN0b21lcl9pZCI6MTcsImFyZWEiOjEzLCJhZGRyZXNzIjoiQ2FsYXZpIiwicGhvbmUiOm51bGwsImVtYWlsIjpudWxsLCJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAyNC0wNy0wM1QxNjoyMjo0Mi42MTdaIiwidXBkYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjQtMDctMDNUMTY6MjI6NDIuNjE3WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRfYnkiOm51bGx9XX1dfSwiaWF0IjoxNzI4ODk3MTcxLCJleHAiOjE3Mjg5MDA3NzF9.cnT-TuRJvB19VzP5Ok0zWmvPyrJFF7vlFeV6gbaSkEY
Interestingly, if I manually set a simple cookie value like test, it works perfectly fine.
I also tried encoding the JWT using encodeURIComponent(), but the issue persists. Is there something I am missing in how to properly set a JWT in cookies? Any insights would be appreciated.


Sharing that JWT also shared some personal information about people that may not agree to you sharing that? Did Siège agrree to you share his/her phone number? This is just base64 encoded data of a JSON structire.
I don't really understnad your question. Do you say that you can send an authentication cookie with the value "test" but not with the value of the JWT you pasted above? Can you share any error codes from the console? Did you try differentbrowsers inspector tools?

